# 集約関数でとってきたハッシュ形式のレスポンスを配列で返す方法について

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

JSON のレスポンスを以下のように出したいのですが、詰まっております。
助言いただけないでしょうか。

現在

```
[["book",10],["pen",100]]
```

目標

```
[
 {
  category:book
  amount:10
 },
 {
  category:pen
  amount:100
 }
]
```

現状ソース

controller

```
def index
 @category_history = CategoryHistory.all.group(:category).sum(:amount)
end
```

json.buider

```
json.array! @category_history
```

Answer (score 1):

こちらでどうでしょう？

```rb
# json.buider
json.array! @category_history do |ch|
  json.category ch[0]
  json.amount ch[1]
end
```

jbuilderはREADMEに豊富なサンプルが書いてあるので迷ったら眺めてみるとよいです

https://github.com/rails/jbuilder

Comment: ありがとうございます！解決しました。